# Android to PHP script not working as expected

Tags: php, android

I am trying to access some mySQL data with from my Android app.

I have two files, one that is the Android file and the other is PHP. I am using xxamp for hosting purposes.

I am running into a problem though: when I run my app onto a physical device for testing, the app either doesn't display anything or it crashes.

Please tell me where I need to improve the code or better coding practices since I am extremely new to this.

```
package com.example.httpclient;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Main extends Activity {//originally named GetPrayerTime got from this url
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11560313/getting-info-from-api-using-json?rq=1

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            //originally custom_component
        new Read().execute("Location");

    }

    private class Read extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

            protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    JSONObject json = retrieveInfo(""); 
                    //create an instance of json object and make it to 
                    //the value returned by retrieveinfo method. Retrieveinfo passes nothing info because
                    //the URL that will be declared will not be modified
                    return json.getString(arg0[0]);
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String status) {
                super.onPostExecute(status);
                //pd.dismiss();

                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        Main.this).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("location");
                alertDialog.setMessage(status);
                alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Main.this.finish();
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
                alertDialog.show();

            }


    public JSONObject retrieveInfo(String user) throws ClientProtocolException,
            IOException, JSONException {
        StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(
                "http://10.0.0.1:1234/htdocs/android_project/all_location_array_display");
        //url.append(user);

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url.toString());
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(get);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        JSONObject timeline = new JSONObject(data);
        return timeline.getJSONObject("");
    }


    }

}


     <?php

//peliminary stuff
$response = array();
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';
$db = new DB_CONNECT();


//let us get all the rows out using mysqli_query
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM location") or die(mysql_error());


//since we need to know if something is actually in the table we need to       //check this by using a if statement checking to see the number of rows

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
//loop through the full table
//building a single object in the response array defined above
    $response["location"] = array();    

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

//define a temporary array location_test[]
    $location_test = array();
 //now we need to fill in the location details using the variables           //from table
    $location_test["pid"] = $row["pid"];
    $location_test["time"] = $row["time"];
    $location_test["location"] = $row["location"];

// now that we an array that has the nescessary details,
//we need to push this into the $response array we defined to make 
//a single location entry for a certain time
    array_push($response["location"], $location_test);
}
echo json_encode($response);
}

?>
```

Comment: When you put it on a device you don't have access to 10.0.0.1 as it's typically a private address. Try finding a hosting provider or setting up a VPS. Alternatively, you could forward the ports and access via an IP or do some network configuration (not recommended)

Comment: I do not know about that, since almost all of the tutorials i have looked and examined follow the same route as i have either by using WAMP or XAMP. For my own benefit please do eleborate on why my approach will not work using an external device instead of an emulator?

Comment: It means that it's attached specifically to your private network, and unless you're connected to it on your device you won't have access. In many cases, your network configuration won't allow it even if you're connected, unless you set it up specifically to do so.

Comment: Interesting so i did a little more research and its recommended that if you use 127.0.01. Does it still lie within the same dimension as you have mentioned? if so, please guide me toward how can i set up my project to allow me to test the app out with a connection to mysql from my localhost. If it helps, I think my presentation will allows me to have the app not fully integrated onto an android device but just test out the functionality of the app on the device will its still attached to my laptop which has Xamp set up on it.

Answer (score 0):

class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask {

```
        @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {

            //------------------>>
            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();


            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


                JSONObject Jobject  =   new JSONObject(data);
                JSONArray Jarray    =      Jobject.getJSONArray("Location");//Name your array


                for (int i = 0; i < Jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object   = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String Pid  =object.getString("nama");
                    String Time = object.getString("logo");
                    String Location =object.getInt("id");

                    //This Get your object in array


                }
                return true;                    

            }                   

        }catch (ParseException e1){
            e1.printStackTrace();

        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }               

        return false;
    }
```

I'm Recommend you the using Retrofit and okhttp or Volley the library for the simple get Json and Faster

Comment: Sorry for not responding to your comment, I really appreciate you posting a code for me to test out. However I have not had the time to test it. But as soon as i do, I will post results for you and maybe some follow up questions. If you have time please do take a look. Thanks!